# Can you help on complex analysis problem

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, roots, maximum-principle, rouches-theorem

The question: Let $D = {z : |z| < 1}$, and let $f : D → D$ have a zero of order $n$ at zero.
Show that $|f(z)| ≤ |z|^{n}$ on $D$.

My attempt: I am not sure what theorem's are applied to this problem I think we use Rouche's Theorem but there may be some problems with that theorem. Do I consider the function $g(z) = f(z) - z$; or could I use the function $h(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z}$ and try to use the maximum modulus principle. I think I am not heading in the right direction. Can you please give me some hints on how to approach this problem? Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Do you know (Schwarz lemma) ? [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma ]. Try to apply induction on n and look at $\frac{f(z)}{z}$. This is, of course, an application of Maximum Modulus Principle.

Comment: Oh I get it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One doesn't even need induction; consider $f(z)/z^n$ directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ has at $z=0$ a zero of order $n$, then 
$$
g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z^n}
$$
is analytic in the unit disk.

If $0<r<1$ and $M_r=\max_{|z|\le r}|g(z)|$, then
$$
M_r=\max_{|z|\le r}|g(z)|=\max_{|z|= r}\frac{|f(z)|}{|z|^n}\le \frac{1}{r^n}
$$
Maximum principle implies that
$$
\sup_{|z|<1}|g(z)|=\lim_{r\to 1}M_r\le \lim_{r\to 1}\frac{1}{r^n}= 1.
$$
Hence
$$
|f(z)|=|g(z)||z|^n\le |z|^n,
$$
for all $|z|<1$.

Note. If $|f(z)|=|z|^n$, for some $|z|<1$, then there exists an $a\in\mathbb C$, with $|a|=1$, such that $f(z)=az^n$, for all $|z|<1$, due to maximum principle.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since the image of $f$ is $\mathbb D$, $|f|\le 1$.
2. Consider $h(z)=f(z)z^{-n}$ which is clearly analytic on $\mathbb D$.
3. By maximum modulus principle, $|h(z)|$ is maximized on $\partial\mathbb D$.
4. Thus, $$\max |h(z)|=\max_{|z|=1}|f(z)||z|^{-n}=\max_{|z|=1}|f(z)|\le 1$$
5. $|h|\le 1\implies|f|\le|z|^n$ on $\mathbb D$.